# DataGridView - Can focus be placed on the blank row with the (*) using code?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, insert, row

On a data grid view there is a blank row with a (*) in it that allows the user to insert a new row of data.

Is there a way to put focus on that row using code even though the data grid view has many rows already loaded in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dgv2.CurrentCell = dgv2(0, dgv2.Rows.Count - 1)
```