# Set focus to a row in datagridview that has been newly inserted or updated?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

How do I set focus to a row in datagridview that has been newly inserted or updated? So the one inserting/Updating doesnt have to go find the data that the user has inserted/updated.

Can I use this =>
([DataGridView - Can focus be placed on the blank row with the (*) using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641749/datagridview-can-focus-be-placed-on-the-blank-row-with-the-using-code))

Comment: when you update a row or insert a row, you should know how to identify that row in your grid and perform the `selecting` manually.

Answer (score 4):

Good morning,

```
if (theGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            theGrid.CurrentCell = theGrid.Rows[theGrid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
        }
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
```

Go to last Row and find the new Row.

Answer (score 2):

try,it might proof helpful to you,

```
     // dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.Focus();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2];
```

If it ends up with cross thread blah blah..
then just invoke new method.

Comment: i updated, its working,if it also works for you mark it as an answer.

Comment: it did not work too.. the focus of Datagridview just stays on the first row of the datagridview.

Comment: focus() was to set focus to grid in case grid not in focus,its working on my end,dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2]; also  check grid selectionmode should be rowheaderselect

Comment: yes it is working, but I want it to select the newly inserted row.

Answer (score 1):

just change row index

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[datagridview.rows.count].Cells[2];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "**just change row index**".

Comment: debug more to understand concept in deep,int x=0;//x is your row index to which you want to set focus to,int y=0;//y column index dataGridView1.CurrentCell =dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y];

Answer (score 0):

```
int LastIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
dataGridView1.Rows[LastIndex].Cells[1].Focus();
```

That's how you do it in asp.net c#